# PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied aws ec2

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, jupyter-notebook

I am using AWS EC2 for my final year project, and I am starting to set up Python and spark to do the big data analysis.

I am following this website: [Jupyter Notebooks on AWS EC2 in 15 (mostly easy) steps](https://medium.com/@alexjsanchez/python-3-notebooks-on-aws-ec2-in-15-mostly-easy-steps-2ec5e662c6c6)

When I did step 13 and type `jupyter notebook` in my terminal, I cannot access the website? And this error occurs:

> PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied

Any idea what could be causing this?

Answer (score 2):

this OS error i think

if somewhere you were specifying path and that path have "/" infront 
OR you have to change the directory permission use this command

```
chown -R user-id:group-id /path/to/the/directory
```

change the permission so web server can access the directory

to check which user of your server own the ownership of web server you can try this command

```
ps aux | grep httpd | grep -v grep
```

Comment: still can't open the Jupyter notebook server